# С учетом того(,) что...

Tags: пунктуация

Окупаемость солнечной станции при продаже энергии составляет 3–4 года, а с учетом того(,) что рост стоимости электроэнергии продолжается, этот срок может ограничиться и 2–3 годами.

Нужна ли в этом случае запятая? Если бы это было начало предложения, я бы не ставила запятую. А как быть здесь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, есть такой составной союз *"с учетом того что"*, в начале предложения не ставилась бы запятая, но в вашем примере стоит её поставить ввиду того, что есть интонационное разделение,  к тому же это помогает избежать стыка союзов.